# Django 2: Can't import models and save it

Tags: python, django-2.0

I somehow can not import my models from another app. I already looked it up and tried but does not work.

**events/models.py**

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        payment = Payment.objects.create(registration=self)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I run python manage.py makemigrations I get this.

**Error**

```
File "C:\Users\Rubber\ems\events\models.py", line 5, in <module>
   from payments.models import Payment   
File "C:\Users\Rubber\ems\payments\models.py", line 6, in <module>
   from events.models import Registration 
ImportError: cannot import name 'Registration'
```

**payments/models.py**

```
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

from events.models import Registration  # THIS WONT WORK


def _create_uuid():
    return uuid.uuid1()

def _get_uuid():
    return _create_uuid()

class Payment(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=_get_uuid)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    registration = models.ForeignKey(Registration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular import. In this case, you can avoid it by removing the `Registration` import and using the string instead:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    registration = models.ForeignKey('events.Registration', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Another option would be to move the `Payment.objects.create()` code into a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save). Note that your current `save()` method creates a `Payment` *every* time the registration is saved, which might not be what you want.

Comment: I tried this before, now I get **save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'registration'.**

Comment: Just reread the error. I switch the super().save() and payments.objects.create(). Works.
Thanks for help.